# Google Plus sharing - wrong image

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to deal with a strange behavior of G+ sharing.
I wrote two lightweight HTML pages to demonstrate my problem. Those pages are almost identical except images in their bodies. On the first page, the content image is much larger that the og:image. On the second page, the content image is slightly smaller than the og:image.

First HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Test page" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="This is page for G+ strange behavior testing." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/wikimania2014/thumb/e/e2/Ask-Logo-Small.jpg/250px-Ask-Logo-Small.jpg" />
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Hello world!</p>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Fronalpstock_big.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="Test page" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="This is page for G+ strange behavior testing." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/wikimania2014/thumb/e/e2/Ask-Logo-Small.jpg/250px-Ask-Logo-Small.jpg" />
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Hello world!</p>
            <img src="http://previewcf.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/07/05__19_56_51/01.jpg90ddaa05-e3a9-4607-b466-29ade8412934Small.jpg" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that in the first case, G+ shows the image from the body (ignores og:image). In the second case, G+ shows og:image as expected.

I've also tried using schema microdata, but the behavior is the same.
I share pages using `https://plus.google.com/share?url=PAGE_URL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The reason was that in the second case, the og:image had smaller width than G+ requires.